# REST api for field validation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, validation

I have to create a couple of web services for validating possible values of given fields. I'm contemplating having something like:

```
POST /entity/fieldName body { fieldValues }
```

where the POST will return 400 (Bad request) if the arguments are invalid and 422 (Unprocessable entity) otherwise. However I do not really like the 422 response part very much since it makes the request always return an error. On the other hand since I'm only doing validation and this is a POST I don't want to actually create a new resource on the server (i.e. return 200). Is there another HTTP method / API endpoint that is better suit for this? For what it's worth I will be checking that the entity field with `<fieldName>` has its value in a given range.

Comment: Well, as the endpoint is for *validating purposes* in my opinion it should return **422 Unprocessable Entity** if the entity is not valid (instead of **400 bad request**) and **200 OK** if the entity is valid.

Comment: @BackSlash, but doesn't using POST and returning 200 imply that a new resource has been created on the server? Because nothing like this will actually happen.

Comment: I think that "A new resource has been created" is **201 Created**. 200 OK means "Request was processed and everything was ok" to me. But I'm definitely not a REST expert, so let's wait for others' answers/comments

Comment: @BackSlash, thanks! You are right, I think - I popped into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860645/create-request-with-post-which-response-codes-200-or-201-and-content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you do is validating, then I think you should send `422` by validation error and `200` by validation success. The POST does not mean you have to always create a new entity.

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a
>   resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200
>   (OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending
>   on whether or not the response includes an entity that describes the
>   result.
>
> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header (see section 14.30).

- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm prefer [google's api error response style](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors).

So my service sends error response as json or xml and `400 Bad request` error code:

```
{
  "status": "INVALID_REQUEST",
  "type": "ERROR_MSG",
  "data": {
    "request": "/v2/data?age=23d",
    "errors": [
      "age: not a number"
    ]
  },
  "time": -1
}
```

otherwise `200` and corresponding message