# My API post request using httpclient returns 200 yet postman returns 201

Tags: c#, api, post

I have the following code to check the endpoint after doing a POST request to the same endpoint

```
    public async Task<int> PostRequestReponseStatus()
    {
        {
            var apiResponse = await client.GetAsync(urlPost);
            int StatusNumber = (int)apiResponse.StatusCode;
            return StatusNumber;
        }
    }
```

And this returns a success response but 200
However when posting to the endpoint with POSTMAN I get a 201 which is what I need. ANy ideas why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create request with POST, which response codes 200 or 201 and content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860645/create-request-with-post-which-response-codes-200-or-201-and-content)

Comment: Thanks but I'm really after feedback on my code above as to why it doesn't return 201.

Comment: In your code you do a GET request (`HttpClient.GetAsync`), not a POST request, whereas in Postman you are probably doing a POST request. So with your HttpClient you fetch some data from the server who responds with 200 (Ok), whereas in Postman you posted some data and the server returned 201 (Created).

Comment: Oops, yes good spot. Not sure how to accept your answer?